# Sonar maven plugin doesn't see the parent class in the classpath

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am trying to write a custom sonarqube plugin. I took the example from the [sonarqube howto article](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101), see the AvoidSuperClassRule class. I run the analysis via mvn sonar:sonar, but the problem is that it can not get the parent class name:

```
String superClassName = treeClazz.superClass().symbolType().fullyQualifiedName();
```

returns "!unknownSymbol!".

My super class is just another class in the sources. I tried with the dependency in the jar file declared via maven dependency section, but with the same result. 
How do I make sonar to load my classes into the classpath so that "symbolType()" returns the real type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compile the project before running the analysis:
`mvn package sonar:sonar`

SonarJava analyzer need to access compiled classes to properly resolve types.